# How do I create instance of class implementing generic interface with base type

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

Lets say I have this:

```
public class BaseEntity {}

public class Product : BaseEntity {}

public interface IPreLoad<T> where T : BaseEntity 
{
    void Preload();
}

public class ProductService : IPreload<Product> 
{
    public void Preload()
    {
        //Do something
    }
}

//Returns list of types implementing IPreload<>
var preloaders = typeFinder.FindClassesOfType(typeof(IPreLoad<>)).ToList(); 

foreach (var preloaderType in preloaders)
{
    var preloader = (IPreLoad<BaseEntity>)EngineContext.Current.ResolveUnregistered(preloaderType);
    cacheManager.Get(preloader.PreLoadCacheKey, () => preloader.PreLoad());
}
```

The issue I have is that I can't cast a `ProductService : IPreLoad<Product>` to a `IPreLoad<BaseEntity>` and I don't know how else I can cast this to achieve the same result. Basically, I want to create an instance of this service and call preload.

Not performing the cast works fine and it creates an instance but then as I haven't cast it as anything, I can't make any calls to it based on the interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interface should be covariant:

```
public interface IPreLoad<out T> where T : BaseEntity 
{
    void Preload();
}
```

Then, assigment will be ok:

```
IPreLoad<BaseEntity> preLoader = new ProductService();
```

Comment: Ahh, so that's what resharper meant when it said to change to covariant :) Excellent, many thanks.

Comment: @webnoob Exactly :) More on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd799517%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for that, was just about to search for a reference document to read up on them. It pretty much describes my exact scenario ^^

Answer (score 0):

In your example, The Preload Method is not affected by the generic type T, you could use a non generic interface like

```
public interface IPreLoad
{
    void Preload();
}

public interface IPreLoad<T>: IPreload where T : BaseEntity 
{
   // your other typed methods...
}
```

then you cast your objects as `IPreload` instead of `IPreLoad<BaseEntity>`